# I have an encoding Problem with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, utf-8

I wrote in a variable `String name = "Marco Nuñez"` but when i print the result with a LOGGER.debug it print `NU�EZ`

Well i think i do everything , i parsed the text forcing using utf-8.

I change my

```
<properties>
  <java.version>11</java.version>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
```

also i change my configuracion of intellij with the project encoding UTF-8

and finally i run my code with

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

So , i open to try all the solutions.

Thanks you 4 your help

EDIT:

I wrote this code ->

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileManagerImpl.class);

----


LOGGER.debug("JAIRO RAFAEL NUÑEZ ALEMAN");
```

and i got this log ->

```
 [nio-9081-exec-2] c.i.i.services.impl.FileManagerImpl      : JAIRO RAFAEL NU�EZ ALEMAN
```

This is my `mvn -verbose`

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\Users\DELL\.m2\wrapper\dists\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\1iopthnavndlasol9gbrbg6bf2\apache-maven-3.6.3
Java version: 11.0.18, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11
Default locale: es_MX, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

UPDATE 2:

When I use

`System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out), true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

it prints the text in console correctly , but now , how can i convert my project encoding and my strings to utf-8

When i do a

`LOGGER.debug("My project encoding is : "+ Charset.defaultCharset());`

i recibe

```
My project encoding is : windows-1252
```

Comment: Make sure your source file is actually saved as a UTF-8 file.  Most text editors will show you the encoding of the file being edited.

Comment: (1) What is your operating system? Windows or something else? (2) Try the following command `mvn -verbose` (3) paste command output here.

Comment: If I save a file containing `"JAIRO RAFAEL NUÑEZ ALEMAN"` in `ISO 8859-1` encoding and re-open it as `UTF-8`, I get `"JAIRO RAFAEL NU�EZ ALEMAN"`

Comment: VGR -> Yes , in my intelli J editor is setted with UTF-8 encoding

Comment: I think I was somewhat ambiguous, it is not how I receive the data in some other encoding, as if I write a String variable with a value with Ñ my program does not show it correctly

Comment: @MichaelAdolfoHuertaRamirez  Can you verify that your console encoding in Intellij-IDEA is UTF-8? On my version (2023.1 Beta) you can do that by inspecting **File > Settings > Editor > General > Console > Default Encoding**. If necessary, change it to _UTF-8_ to see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Yes, my default encoding is utf - 8

Comment: @MichaelAdolfoHuertaRamirez OK. [1] What logger are you using - slf4j? [2] Try adding a call to `System.out.println("Marco Nuñez");` to your application. If that renders correctly in the console then the problem may be with your logger's configuration. But if that also doesn't render correctly then precede the call to `println()` with a call to `System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out), true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`. Does the `println()` call work after doing that?

Comment: Yes, it works wit  ```System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out), true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); ``` , now how can i set the new string with utf 8? ¿i need to convert?

Comment: What to do next depends on what you are using as your logger, so update your question with that information, plus any details of any configuration you have done for that logger.

Comment: I edited the post , now i want to send a string to another part but it stills failing the encode, the only that works now is the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , i do this change to my user enviroments and this works!

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF
```

Maven uses utf-8 configuration from pom.xml, but maven uses system java configuration

Comment: Good that you resolved your issue but your final sentence is unclear. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what logging package are you using?

Next, What exactly are you expecting as an output? Are you expecting "Marco Nuñez"?

I created a sample using Logger from org.sl4j and did not do additional setup.

```
package com.deanpinlac.loggerdemo;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Controller {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Controller.class);

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String test(){
        String name = "Marco Nuñez";
        logger.debug(name);
        return name;
    }
}
```

Output:

> 2023-03-08T22:01:13.057-05:00 DEBUG 16528 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.deanpinlac.loggerdemo.Controller     : Marco Nuñez

Comment: I update the question with my log print

Comment: Asking the OP several questions in your answer is a red flag that you should have asked for more information before answering at all. Requests for more information should be posted as comments to the question itself. And merely demonstrating that you don't have a problem in your environment (which may be, and probably is, completely different to that of the OP) does nothing help the OP with their specific problem.

Comment: It requires 50 reputation to comment on the question.